# Create a static (no scroll) web page

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create a static home page (hence, no scrolls) that will take all the width and height available on the screen. Like this https://getuikit.com/ or http://underco.fr/

Basically I've tried to set `height: 100%` to both `html`and `body`but as I have a navigation bar, it creates a scroller.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to achive this. I recomend you setting paddings and margins to 0 and using vh for height
or you can do this to:

```
body {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```